# Buildship keeps overwriting .classpath

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship, eclipse-classpath

I'm using Gradle and Eclipse with the Buildship plugin.

Buildship creates the `.classpath` file for Eclipse to use. I need one classpath entry (`com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER`) to appear after the `org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer` entry, for class-loading reasons.

So the relevant part of my `.classpath` file should look like this (having the `GWT_CONTAINER` on the bottom).

```
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer" />
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"/>
</classpath>
```

Buildship always has the `gradleclasspathcontainer` on the last position. So I tried to change the sorting like this in my `build.gradle` (excerpt):

```
eclipse {
    classpath { 
        file {
            beforeMerged { classpath ->
                def gwtClasspath = classpath.entries.find { entry -> entry.path == 'com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER' }
                classpath.entries.remove gwtClasspath
                classpath.entries << gwtClasspath
            }
        }
    }
```

When using `./gradlew eclipseClasspath`, the `.classpath` file is created correctly. But as soon as Buildship runs, the file is again overwritten with the wrong ordering.

I also tried using `whenMerged` instead of `beforeMerged`, but that doesn't change anything.

Here's the output of Gradle when started by Buildship (e.g. by clicking on Gradle -> Refresh on the Eclipse project's properties):

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 0s
:cleanEclipseWtpComponent
:cleanEclipseWtpFacet
:cleanEclipseWtp
:eclipseWtpComponent
:eclipseWtpFacet
:eclipseWtp

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
```

It seems Buildship doesn't even execute the `eclipseClasspath` task, but does create the `.classpath` file by some other means.

How can I get Buildship to honor my wish to have the classpath sorted my way?

Comment: Would the [_GWT Gradle Plugin_](https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin) be an option for you?

Comment: I'm already using this (that's where the classpath entry for GWT is coming from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [solution on Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-does-buildship-create-the-classpath-file-for-eclipse/26252):

Buildship doesn't use the `eclipseClasspath` task, but reads the configuration and creates `.classpath` by its own means. The Gradle classpath is appended to the end of the classpath, if it's not yet defined. This happens after executing the `whenMerged` section. So the solution is to add the Gradle classpath manually:

```
eclipse {
   classpath {
        containers 'org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `withXml` hook would work differently

```
eclipse.classpath.file {
    withXml { provider ->
        def entry = provider.asNode().classpath.classpathentry.find { it.path == 'com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER' }
        println "Found $entry"
        def parent = entry.parent()
        parent.remove(entry)
        parent.append(entry)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't change the result :(

Comment: What did the println output?

Comment: I just noticed Buildship doesn't execute the `eclipseClasspath` task. So there is no output from this task, but still the `.classpath` file is there after Buildship ran. So the problem is probably that Buildship uses other means to create this file.
Buildship runs the following tasks: `eclipseWtpComponent`, `eclipseWtpFacet` and `eclipseWtp`. If I delete `.classpath` and run Gradle manually with those tasks, it does not create a new `.classpath` file.

Comment: Buildship should fire the `eclipseClasspath` task every time you right click on the project and choose "refresh gradle project" (there's also a refresh button in the buildship view). How did the `GWT_CONTAINER` get into your `.classpath`? Did you add it manually? Any additions should be done via `build.gradle` and not manually

Comment: I'm using the GWT plugin (linked in the first comment below the question). According to its log, Buildship does not use the `eclipseClasspath` task.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't use the `eclipseClasspath` task, but it does use the `eclipse.classpath` model from `build.gradle`. If you are not adding `GWT_CONTAINER` in `build.gradle` then I'm pretty sure that's your problem. Everything needs to be in `build.gradle` and nothing can be added to `.classpath` by another external process/plugin (it's fine that GWT plugin reads the GWT_CONTAINER entry and acts accordingly). Perhaps you also need to add the GWT nature in build.gradle?

Comment: According to the GWT Gradle Plugin documentation, it automatically adds the GWT nature. And the classpath includes the `GWT_CONTAINER`, but only at the wrong location.

Comment: Ok, if its gradle adding then that's fine. So, does the println in the  `withXml` closure execute when you "refresh gradle project" in eclipse? Does it find the GWT entry?

Comment: No, it doesn't even execute the `eclipseClasspath` task, so the `withXml` part is not executed, too. I'll add some log info to the question.

Comment: Agreed, but it should still use the eclipse model, which includes `withXml`

Comment: Same goes for `beforeMerged` or `whenMerged`, but it doesn't.